# Can we change the name of the chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Other Stack Exchange sites have interesting and descriptive names for their chat rooms while ours is just "Programmers". Would it be possible to change it to something more like those sites?

Let's call a deadline of a week, we'll have to decide by Friday 27th @ 20:00 (UTC). That's a poll but I've got mod backing.

---

And we have a winner: The Whiteboard!

Comment: Add "The Whiteboard" as an answer, so people can vote for (or against) it. Yes, I'm perfectly aware I'm turning this into a poll, and for sanity's sake I'd like you to put a deadline to it, perhaps a week (?).

Comment: Related: [What should the name of our chat room be?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-room-be) (on Meta Workplace)

Answer (score 17):

I propose "The Whiteboard" as the new name of the chat room.

Answer (score 4):

I propose "My code's compiling"

Comment: That's... true ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos - I suppressed the urge to propose "Ask Yannis"

Comment: Heh, I managed to squeeze it in there ;)